# 'new Date()' in IE11 does not accept string in ISO 8701 date format with a timezone

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

The following call to the Date constructor call works in Chrome, Mozilla, and Edge, but not in IE11:

```
new Date("2018-11-01T04:00:00.000+1000");
```

*Note: I receive the date string from server response and therefore, I have no control over it*

In IE11 only, I get `Invalid Date` as a returned value. I figured out that it was because of the format of the timezone marker (`+` onward) because the following call works as intended:

```
new Date("2018-11-01T04:00:00.000"); // No timezone
```

As well as this one:

```
new Date("2018-11-01T04:00:00.000+10:00"); // Formatted timezone
```

What ways are there to get a Date object from the string `"2018-11-01T04:00:00.000+1000"` in IE11?

Splicing the `:` in the appropriate place seems to do the job, but I am not sure it is the best solution.

Thank you!

Comment: I try to find any other way to pass the date in IE with time zone but nothing works. So at present, It looks like split the date from time zone is the solution that can work for you. I will try to search further and if get any better way than I will try to inform you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem ended up being, as I described, splicing `:` in the correct spot it didn't already exist:

```
// Call this after making sure the date doesn't contain the : at the appropriate position
function formatExtendedTimezoneIn(originalDate) {
    const timezoneDivisorIndex = originalDate.length - 4;

    const arr = originalDate.split('');
    arr.splice(timezoneDivisorIndex+2, 0, ':');
    return arr.join('');
}
```